# Create customized colorbar in python for matplotlib blue-white-orange-red

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I would like to reproduce this colorbar using matplotlib. It should be also usable for other ranges and stepping. But still having the zero in white, all negative blue, positive going from yellow/orange to red.[image: colorbar blue-white-orange-red]

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? Did you already create some short test code?

Comment: what about using colormap already cretaed as RdYlBu?

Comment: When using RdYlBu you are not diverging around zero and have no white for around zero points.  I tried few solutions for other colorbars from stackoverflow or internet. No one could satified me as color were missing or there was no explaination how to manage the stepping. 
Let ask me so: if you would need to code this colorbar for matplotlib, how would your code look like?

Comment: @KuKaKi Did you ever find a solution to your question - I'm trying to do something similar.

Comment: Hi @Josh, I didnt and decided to use a different kind of colorbar. But I am still interested in case you have a solution for it.